# How is table layout fixed rendered?

Tags: html, css

How is table layout fixed rendered?
According to 17.5.2.1 "Fixed table layout" (from W3):

> In the fixed table layout algorithm, the width of each column is determined as follows:
>
> 1.A column element with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property sets the width for that column.
>
> 2.Otherwise, a cell in the first row with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property determines the width for that column.

I take it that first we check the width of the col element, and if it's set to something like 100px then we use it and nothing else.
However the following layout proves me wrong. It's as if the browser calculates MAX(col.width, first-td.width).
What am I missing here? Did I misunderstand the W3 definition?
Thanks

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/91qozmnb/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col />
        <col />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>test1
            </td>
            <td>test2
            </td>
            <td>test3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table
{
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-spacing:0px;
}
table > colgroup > col:nth-child(1)
{
    width:100px;
}
table > colgroup > col:nth-child(2)
{
    width:150px;
}
table > colgroup > col:nth-child(3)
{
    width:200px;
}
table > tbody > tr > td
{
    border:5px solid lightgray;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)
{
    width:200px;
}
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)
{
    width:150px;
}
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)
{
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: What browser(s) did you try this on?

Comment: A very interesting effect in Chrome. Set table { width: 300px;} and it will work ok. (any value under the minimum will work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading further in the spec, you will find

> 17.5.2.1 Fixed table layout
>
> With this (fast) algorithm, the horizontal layout of the table does
>   not depend on the contents of the cells; it only depends on the
>   table's width, the width of the columns, and borders or cell spacing.
>
> The table's width may be specified explicitly with the 'width'
>   property. A value of 'auto' (for both 'display: table' and 'display:
>   inline-table') means use the **automatic table layout** algorithm.
>   However, if the table is a block-level table ('display: table') in
>   normal flow, a UA may (**but does not have to**) ...

So, if you want to make sure that fixed table layout is **used at all**, set the width property of the table

Comment: Thanks!
I didn't pay enough attention to the spec, now I see my mistake.